# Latch/lid opening maneuver (videos in comments)

Tags: animation, armature

A brilliant fellow gave me a VERY thorough answer on how to animate my latch/lid opening
( https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTGsY.jpg ) although it's too complex for a rookie like me to set up myself.

"The main control rotates marker bones with floor constraints that control their potential positions, and then the deforming bones track those markers. You can rotate the control about any pivot to get different interpolation. To adjust the angles/behavior, transform the floor bones (the bones that are the targets of the floor constraints) to eye in pose mode and then use ctrl-a apply selected as rest pose for those bones."

Despite getting a great answer to my question, I'm still stuck. I'm in over my head and don't know how to implement all these steps.  Any ELI5 would be greatly appreciated.

\[image]

Comment: Do you have an example of what it's supposed to look like?

Comment: Here's the maneuver https://imgur.com/a/SwIuKUa

Comment: Here's what I'm working with https://imgur.com/a/Sl7oBdc